# Avoid doubling selections in NSMutbleArray

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a simple questionnaire app that uses tableview. When  users answers questions they  have option to step back and change the selection they made. That causes doubling answers in results (the selections are stored in NSmutableArray) How to escape storing "double" results in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *add= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (Item *item in addList){
        if ([add containsObject:item])
        { // Do not add
        }
        else
            [add addObject:item];
}
```

Here addList is list of objects

Answer (score 0):

First the array should be of NSMutableArray type, then check if the object to be inserted exists or not

```
if([yourMutableArray containsObject:valueToBeStored]){
NSLog(@"do not add");

}
else{
[yourMutableArray addObject:valueToBeStored];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `NSMutableArray` to a `NSMutableSet`. Make sure your answer's `isEqual:` considers only the question number that is being answered. Also implement `- (NSUInteger)hash`, but it might work without.

Answer (score 0):

I've made the assumption that in going back, the only way a user can go forward is to answer the question again and that the selections (answers) are stored in the array in the order they are answered.

In that case, all you need to do it remove the last object in the array each time you step back.

```
[selections removeLastObject];
```

It gets a bit more complicated if you're allowing them to move backwards and forwards, but essentially you hold onto the current index and decrement or increment it as you move backward or forward respectively.

You then use this index to replace the object in the array at the current index when the user selects a new answer.

```
[selections replaceObjectAtIndex:currentQuestionIndex withObject:newSelection];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your array to a `NSMutableSet` or, if you need the sorting, use `NSMutableOrderedSet`. This basically behaves like a `NSMutableArray` but checks for double entries with `isEqual:`.

Answer (score -1):

Use following code in where you call your method...

```
[yourArray removeAllObjects];
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: This will just remove objects from  the array. I'm trying to prevent doubling results.

Comment: You can write it before where you fill yourArray. Then you can get only single values.